# How to specialize a recursive enum const generic?

Tags: rust

```rust
#![feature(adt_const_params)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Director {
    Go(&'static Director),
    Stop,
}
pub struct Test<const D: Director>();
impl<const B: Director> Test<{ Director::Go(&B) }> {
    fn run() {
        println!("go");
        Test::<B>::run();
    }
}
impl Test<{ Director::Stop }> {
    fn run() {
        println!("stopped");
    }
}

const A: Director = Director::Go(&Director::Go(&Director::Stop));
fn main() {
    Test::<A>::run();
}
```

And when compile:

```
error[E0207]: the const parameter `B` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:13:6
   |
13 | impl<const B:Director> Test<{Director::Go(&B)}>{
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unconstrained const parameter
   |
   = note: expressions using a const parameter must map each value to a distinct output value
   = note: proving the result of expressions other than the parameter are unique is not supported
```

It seems like when I use enum as a const generic and specialize it,I must give the exactly value which can judge the equality rather than just destruct it.

But i think there is enough info in my code for compiler to specialize the generic.

Is it my syntax fault?

Comment: The "parameter is not constrained" error is usually for situations where you have some `Test<{Director::Go(_)}>` type in use, and the compiler needs to deduce the generic parameter `B` in order to do method lookup, satisfy trait constraints, and whatnot. It seems simple to you or I how to figure that out, but I'm guessing since you're messing with *incomplete features* that this may just not be implemented yet.